# Metacoin - why does `send` show the contract address in `receipt.to`?

Tags: truffle

I've recently started learning web3 and am playing with truffle.

```
truffle(develop)> truffle migrate
...
 Deploying 'MetaCoin'
   --------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x70e37bc9344cea80f549b27425b3eec6e5fb220e71aed35110d8568664cddb38
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xa887F1417CaAfFaaD2Db630Aa92de89181569EAd
   > block number:        2
   > block timestamp:     1695166254
   > account:             0x9352Ce044E313D9F9bc628C42018E987d0Ea97E3
   > balance:             99.9981051633782056
   > gas used:            416700 (0x65bbc)
   > gas price:           3.270753832 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.0013629231217944 ETH
...
truffle(develop)> let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed()
truffle(develop)> instance
TruffleContract {
...
  address: '0xa887F1417CaAfFaaD2Db630Aa92de89181569EAd',
...
truffle(develop)> let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
undefined
truffle(develop)> accounts
[
  '0x9352Ce044E313D9F9bc628C42018E987d0Ea97E3',
  '0xb019e32401F03e2A117Cb8A4d07f7d976D6160F5',
  '0x452eEC3fc0329786ebdBa3E1865838a92eEeBfd5',
  '0x858954748407711Ac808491e687Ab99e6a9D7793',
  '0x48ACdF5Ec291657a7BA2F3A60e0B04560d753246',
  '0x0f0433476469DB6a17D507Ae23DDbB405DdB674C',
  '0xe245db1B4C584bB28FaB451b49CFf1394FEA58A5',
  '0x713f0485a03145dF33cb04f7EE148747A23859Fa',
  '0x4B50EC457088CFecA36CE8210e8Bc51113493f4C',
  '0x6b250a4618d42642Cb42175E94bEC445fE2dc2D8'
]
truffle(develop)> let result = await instance.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10, {from: accounts[0]})
{
  tx: '0x34bf636ec1a7ea271e15094eaf2a6f1310a15bcbb3968c17d6832932a890c805',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x34bf636ec1a7ea271e15094eaf2a6f1310a15bcbb3968c17d6832932a890c805',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockNumber: 3,
    blockHash: '0x8cc1ae722bbdd36c1d96a5d9b6f1093ad6a7531f9d050217ba3bdf81df3ece98',
    from: '0x9352ce044e313d9f9bc628c42018e987d0ea97e3',
    to: '0xa887f1417caaffaad2db630aa92de89181569ead',
    cumulativeGasUsed: 52285,
...
```

And you can see that the `result.receipt.from` is `accounts[0]` but the `result.receipt.to` is the contract address and not `accounts[1]`.

However `accounts[1]` is indeed the one that was sent to and not the contract:

```
truffle(develop)> balance = await instance.getBalance('0xa887f1417caaffaad2db630aa92de89181569ead')
BN { negative: 0, words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }
truffle(develop)> balance.toNumber()
0

truffle(develop)> balance = await instance.getBalance(accounts[1])
BN { negative: 0, words: [ 10, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }
truffle(develop)> balance.toNumber()
10
```

Is this a bug or am I not understanding something?

```
truffle(development)> version
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Ganache v7.9.1
Solidity - 0.8.13 (solc-js)
Node v18.17.1
Web3.js v1.10.0
```

Comment: If I understand correctly then it doesn't sound like a bug. When you transfer a token you are calling a transfer function at the token contract. So contract would be receiver of the transaction, while the function would increase and reduce balances, before letting off a transfer event.

Comment: I see.  That is confusing.  I found out after going through this that Truffle is being shut down.  I will check to see what HardHat does.

Comment: This would be an evm/smart contract thing, so it should be the same in hardhat. You could get a ton of mileage just working with web3.js and leave the development  framework for later. Since as you elude to they are each like learning their own thing and maybe the additional abstraction will get in the way at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation suggesting this is a bug:

- https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/how-to/contracts/interact-with-your-contracts/ says:

> Processing transaction results
>
> When you make a transaction, you're given a result object that gives you a wealth of information about the transaction.
>
> ```
> truffle(develop)> let result = await instance.sendCoin(accounts[1], 10, {from: accounts[0]})
> truffle(develop)> result
> ```
>
> Specifically, you get the following:
>
> ```
>     result.tx (string) - Transaction hash
>     result.logs (array) - Decoded events (logs)
>     result.receipt (object) - Transaction receipt (includes the amount of gas used)
> ```
>
> For more information, please see the README in the @truffle/contract package.

Looking at that README (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract) and through redirects and searches I eventually get to https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html?highlight=receipt#gettransactionreceipt.

That says:

> `from` - String: Address of the sender.
>
> `to` - String: Address of the receiver. null when it’s a contract creation transaction.

So it is a bug.  I will feedback to the project later today.  Comments welcome!

I created https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/6197.  There is no response on that and I guess noone cares now that Truffle is being shuttered (I found that out after I'd gone through all this).

Comment: See Maka's comment on the question